# C++ Functions and 'identifier not found' error

Tags: c++

I'm a C++ learner.I'm trying to code a basic C++ project. It's basic automation system . It has a navigation menu.

```
Choose an option :
   1 ) Add a new customer
   2 ) List all customers
   ...
```

There will be a `nav`variable, which containing user's choice. This is my source code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <clocale>

int nav;    

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"turkish");
    navigasyon();
    switch (nav) // checking 'nav' variable which assigned in navigasyon()
    case "1" :
         printf("Now you are adding a new customer");
    break;
    case "2" :
         printf("Now you are listing all customers");
    break;
}

void navigasyon()
{
    printf("Choose an option \n");
printf("1 ) Add a new customer\n");
printf("2 ) List all customers\n");

scanf("%d", &nav); // assigning '`nav' variable
}
```

In shortly, 
in main() , navigasyon() will show navigation menu, user choose 1 or 2 and then navigasyon() assinging it to `nav` . Lastly checking `nav`with switch-case.

But i'm getting `'navigasyon': identifier not found` error.

Comment: [function prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype)

Comment: Except `#include <clocale>` I don't see any C++ here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should declare `navigasyon` before `main`.

Comment: have i write `setlocale(LC_ALL,"turkish");` to all functions ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare the function first

After your #includes statements write this

```
void navigasyon();
```

Alternatively you can place the function before the main. In C++ a function has to be declared before being used, unless it's placed before the main.

Comment: Nit: that's a declaration, not a definition.

Answer (score 3):

You use `navigasyon` function in `main` before defining it. You need either to switch places of `main` and `navigasyon`, or declare `navigasyon` before `main`.

Answer (score 2):

Place 'navigasyon' above main.

C++ demands that functions are declared before they are used. This can done by placing the whole function before the usage or by forward declaration, where you only have the signature before.

Answer (score 2):

You need a declaration for the `navigasyon()` function at the beginning of your file, so the compiler knows about it when it compiles `main()`:

```
void navigasyon();
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to declare the method before using it. Add the following Line before your main:

```
static void navigasyon();
```

This declares navigasyon as a local only (static) function. For further use you should move the decleration to a .h file, remove the static and of course include this .h file.